# League\Fractal transform item inside array

Tags: php, api, laravel, transformer-model

need a little help with League\Fractal, i'm trying to create object to imitate FeatureCollection of GoogleMapApi DataLayer

```
FeatureCollection
+ type
+ features => [
  Feature
  {
     type,
     geometry => 
          {
          type,
          coordinates => [latitude, longitudes]
          }
   }
]
```

I've successfully create Transformer for Geometry and Feature, yet having a problem with FeatureCollection because attributes features is an array with element of Feature.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        [],
        [],
    ]
}
```

How can i transform the inside of features element correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well somehow i manage to understand the concept. So basically you need to return the ***collection*** with the ObjectTransformer itself, not just the Object.

Just need to add this inside the FeatureCollectionTransformerClass

```
protected $defaultIncludes =[
    'features'
];

public function includeFeatures(FeatureCollection $collection){
    return $this->collection($collection->features, new FeatureTransformer());
}
```